# laravel4 routing with {$url} in route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm new to laravel, actualy i just downloaded it today, and trying to work with it now.
I was watching youtube videos about it, and reading documentation, but laravel documentation is not explaining anything at all...

So i'm trying now to create a new route with {$url} in it.
In route.php i'm writing this:

```
Route::get ( "users/{$url}", "MainController@RequestData" );
```

and in MainController.php i'm creating a new function:

```
public function RequestData ( $url ) {

     return View::make("temp.rData");

}
```

but when i refresh a page all i get  is  ErrorException Undefined variable: url

i tried to define url in RequestData function, but this doesn't seem to work at all... 
I tried was looking for an answer for a long time, most of them are using (:any) or (:all) in case of {$url}, but none of them seems to work for me.

Can anyone help me with this ? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define the parameter without $ and use another word as url is a facade for the url helper so this might be a reserved word in route params.

```
Route::get ( "users/{myurl}", "MainController@RequestData" );


public function RequestData ( $myurl ){}
```

this should help you out :)

Comment: No problem :) If this solution helped, please +1 and mark my answer as accepted so that others facing a similar problem can use this as a solution as well. Best regards,

Comment: I will mark it as answer a few minutes later, but i can't give you +1, becouse i don't have 15 reputation yet :(